# Debugging dynamically generated/loaded JavaScript code INSIDE the host JavaScript

Tags: javascript

The title probably isn't saying much at all, but hopefully it got someone interested.

The actual problem is quite simple.
I want to make a web application that loads JavaScript code dynamically (might even be a hardcoded string) as a string, then I want to run that code line by line and analyze the debug info every step.

Basically, I need a JavaScript interpreter/debugger written in JavaScript.

Hopefully, I'd be able to do something like this

```
var source = "var a = 5; var b = a; b = 6"
var vm = new VirtualMachine(source);
vm.step();
vm.getDebugInfo();
```

and it would tell me about the local variables and their values.

Comment: You are probably trying to do smth like `try { eval("var a = 5; dosmth(a);"); } catch(e) {console.log(e); }`

Comment: That solution really doesn't go far to solving my problem.

Answer (score 0):

This project hasn't been updated in a while but maybe you could build something for your purpose around it

https://github.com/jterrace/js.js/ - A JavaScript JavaScript interpreter

Comment: I saw that, but if it doesn't have built in debug capabilities, I might as well be writing my own interpreter.